# C++ Dereferencing with Parenthesis (with iterators)

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, dereference

My question is pretty simple. I have a vector of values (threads here, irrelevant) and I want to iterate through them. However there are two version of the code which looks same to me but only the second one works. I want to know why.

**Version 1**  (Does not compile)

```cpp
int main(){
    int someValue = 5;
    vector<std::thread *> threadVector;

    threadVector.resize(20);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        threadVector[i] = new std::thread(foo, std::ref(someValue));
    }

    for (std::vector<std::thread *>::iterator it = threadVector.begin(); it != threadVector.end(); ++it) {
        *it->join(); // *********Notice this Line*********
    }

    system("pause"); // I know I shouldn't be using this
}
```

**Version 2**  (Does work)

```cpp
int main(){
    int someValue = 5;
    vector<std::thread *> threadVector;

    threadVector.resize(20);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        threadVector[i] = new std::thread(foo, std::ref(someValue));
    }

    for (std::vector<std::thread *>::iterator it = threadVector.begin(); it != threadVector.end(); ++it) {
        (*it)->join(); // *********Notice this Line*********
    }

    system("pause"); // I know I shouldn't be using this
}
```

Comment: Not only that using `system("pause")` has its issues, but knowing that and still posting this irrelevant code leaves room for improvement. ;) That said, I think that std::thread is movable and thus can be stored in a container (other than e.g. the early boost::thread). I might be mistaken though, as I haven't played with C++11 that much yet.

Comment: So can you explain what is wrong with storing them inside a vector? I mean I can declare a unique_ptr then std::move into the vector but how is that different from a new statement?

Comment: What I'm suggesting is not using a pointer and dynamic allocation at all, for all the exception safety issues and other overhead this presents. Similarly you wouldn't use a `vector<int*>` but a `vector<int>`, or? I'm not sure if you can really avoid it in this case though.

Comment: Ah... yeah dereferencing comes with a cost. There are two reasons why I'm doing this, but I'm open to new ideas. 1) I simply can't create a thread without initializing it. I need to pass in the function, the parameters and start the thread to initialize. But I'm opening threads on the fly so, I have to use with pointers. 2) Threads themselves have a memory cost. I don't want the vector that I'm storing them to constantly resize. Thus the only cost is to store the pointers of the threads. So the finished threads won't have a cost of heap (or stack, in the case of non-ptrs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with order of operations.

```
*it->join();
```

is parsed as:

```
*(it->join());
```

Comment: Found [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Taking it as a challenge, I just dabbed my feet in C++11 for the first time. I have found out that you can achieve the same without any dynamic allocation of `std::thread` objects:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void function()
{
    std::cout << "thread function\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> ths;
    ths.push_back(std::move(std::thread(&function)));
    ths.push_back(std::move(std::thread(&function)));
    ths.push_back(std::move(std::thread(&function)));

    while (!ths.empty()) {
        std::thread th = std::move(ths.back());
        ths.pop_back();
        th.join();
    }
}
```

This works because `std::thread` has a constructor and assignment operator taking an rvalue reference, making it movable. Further, all containers have gained support for storing movable objects and they move instead of copy them on reallocations. Read some online articles about this new C++11 feature, it's too wide to explain here and I also don't know it well enough.

About the concern you raised that threads have a memory cost, I don't think that your approach is an optimization. Rather the dynamic allocation itself has an overhead, both in memory and performance. For small objects, the memory overhead of one or two pointers plus possibly some padding is enormous. I wouldn't be surprised if `std::thread` objects had the size of a single pointer only, giving you an overhead of more than 100%.

Note that this only concerns the `std::thread` object. The memory required for the actual thread, in particular its stack, are a different issue. However, `std::thread` objects and the actual threads don't have a 1:1 relation and dynamic allocation of the `std::thread` object doesn't change anything there either.

If you're still afraid that the reallocations are too expensive, you could reserve a suitable size up front to avoid reallocations. However, if that really is an issue, then you are creating and terminating threads way too much, and that will by far dwarf the overhead of shifting a few, small objects around. Consider using a threadpool.